# Are there any European Commission decisions on the duration of the non-compete clause?

Tags: european-union, corporate-law

Do you know any examples of European Commission decisions on the duration of the non-compete clause/obligations in corporate law? I mean contracts when this non-compete clause was too long according to the European Commission.

I don't mind about the market (from oil delivery contracts to employers -  mine was 6 months in the UK).

Comment: A bit more detail might assist. Do you have any examples that can be reviewed so users can offer a focused answer?

Comment: @RockApe Sure! I'm trying to add some examples. Even if I'm looking to get an idea of the rule from these decisions (which I've heard fluctuated quite a bit). I'm very new to Law, sorry if I don't ask my questions correctly :)

Comment: This sounds like a topic that would be outside of the scope of EU jurisdiction since uniform rules on non-compete clauses are not necessary for the Single Market, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsidiarity_(European_Union)